# Move folders within a date range and preserve security

Tags: windows, powershell, copy, move, windows-server

I am trying to move some old folders (Modified folder date before 01/01/2021) to an archive folder on another Windows server. It must preserve the security parameters. I tried playing around with robocopy, but it would look at the files and move those. I am concerned with the root folders and modified dates.

Is this possible?

Comment: you want to move the data or copy?```robocopy /move``` or if you want to copy ```robocopy  /copy:DATS``` see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Comment: @Toni I originally had 'robocopy \\src\Folder1 \\dst\Folder2 /E /ZB /SECFIX /COPYALL /MOVE /TEE /MINAGE:20210101' but it looked at the file contents of the folders and only moved older files from sub folders. I need it to move the old folders regardless of its contents.

Comment: you only want to move folders with its content or only the files that have: /MINAGE:20210101?

Comment: @Toni "\\src\Folder1" has hundreds of folders. I need to move the folders with its content (which includes sub folders and files while preserving DATS) to "\\dst\Folder2". It is possible that a file in some subdirectory within the source maybe newer than the date in the root folder. I would still need that moved since I want to preserve the root folder contents.